# Two coins, one fair and one double headed

Tags: probability

Two coins: one fair (coin A) and one double headed (coin B). I toss one of the coins and get a head. What's the chance that I tossed coin A?

The answer is $1/3$, but how did they get this?

Comment: welcome to MSE, please try to add some of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\Pr(A\mid H)=\frac{\Pr(H\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(H\mid A)\Pr(A)+\Pr(H\mid B)\Pr(B)}=\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac12}{\frac12\cdot\frac12+1\cdot\frac12}=\frac13.
$$

Answer (score 1):

There are four equally likely outcomes of this experiment which can
be described as $H_A, T_A, H_{B,1}, H_{B,2}$. You have observed a Head.
Only one of the three
possible Heads that you might have observed is $H_A$ and so there is
one chance in three that the Head you actually observed in $H_A$.